# Request had insufficient authentication scopes - Dataflow/Apache Beam on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to run a Beam pipeline (as part of an AI Platform ML training job) on GCP. I'm following the data processing part of [this notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/10_recommend/wals_tft.ipynb) very closely. When I set Beam to use the "DirectRunner", everything runs fine (It's slow though). But as soon as I switch to DataflowRunner, I get an "Insufficient scope" error: (Traceback shortened)

> HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing
>   https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/neurec-252017/locations/us-central1/jobs?alt=json:
>
> response: [...]
>
> content <{   "error": {
>       "code": 403,
>       "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
>       "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"   } }

I have spent quite some time reading answers to similar questions here on SO to no avail. What I understand is that when I launch a Beam pipeline it creates a GCE instance on behalf of my project and that VM does not have the required permission to write to my GCS bucket.

What I cannot figure out is how to set the right scope/permissions for that GCE instance (preferably from within the Python code that launches the Beam pipeline, rather than the GCP console). I tried giving the following permissions to the Compute Engine default service account ([PROJECT_NUMBER]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com):

Compute Instance Admin (v1)

Dataflow Admin

Owner

Storage Admin

But I'm still getting the same error. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: hi Milad, have you been able to resolve this issue since then? I'm running into exactly the same one.

Answer (score 0):

You need the role "Dataflow Admin" which is the minimum role for creating and managing Dataflow jobs.

Assign this role to your account (the one launching the Dataflow runner job) and not the Compute Engine Default Service Account. Return the Compute Engine Default Service Account back the way it was (remove your changes).

[Cloud Dataflow Access Control Guide](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I sign in with my own account when I run gcloud init and then submit the training job from the terminal while logged in with that same account. And that account is already Dataflow Admin.

Comment: @MiladShahidi - The error message says you don't have the correct permissions. This means double-check everything.

Comment: Thank you. I have initialized the project to default and am running the application as my user account and ensuring that I have dataflow-admin, compute-admin, ml-engine-admin, and storage-admin assigned to my user. 
I have set the user and project id via gcloud config, followed by gcloud auth application-default login, leaving the default-service-account as Editor Role as defined during the project initialization.
Still getting the same error.

Comment: What does this command output `gcloud auth list`? Edit your question and show the exact code that you are using (not some external link).

Comment: Double-check the GCE instance. What is the setting for `Cloud API access scopes`? Make sure it is set to `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs`.